# Angular localization with Ivy - $localize - The new localization approach

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

**Configuration for i18n:** Part of the new Angular rendering engine, Ivy, includes a new approach to localizing applications — specifically extracting and translating text

```
"architect": {
      "build": {
                ...
        "options": {
                     ...
                    }
        "configurations": {
              "production": {
                    "assets": [...],
                     "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                     "optimization": true,
                     "outputHashing": "all",
                     "sourceMap": false,
                     "extractCss": true,
                     "namedChunks": false,
                     "aot": true,
                     "extractLicenses": true,
                     "vendorChunk": false,
                     "buildOptimizer": true,
                     "outputPath": "dist/production/nl/",
                     "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.nl.xlf",
                     "i18nLocale": "nl",
                     "baseHref": "/ngapp/nl/"
             }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**New Configuration changes as follows which reduces the build time if working with multiple languages**
https://blog.angular.io/angular-localization-with-ivy-4d8becefb6aa

```
"architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        ...
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "assets": [ ... ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "aot": true,
                            "outputPath": "dist/production",
                            "serviceWorker": true,
                            "localize": [
                                "nl",
                                "en"
                            ]
                        },
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "project:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "project:build:production"
                        },
                        "en": {
                            "browserTarget": "project:build:en"
                        },
                        "nl": {
                            "browserTarget": "project:build:nl"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "project:build"
                    }
                },
                "i18n": {
                "locales": {
                    "nl": {
                        "translation": "src/locale/messages.nl.xlf",
                        "baseHref": "/ngapp/nl/"
                    },
                    "en": {
                        "translation": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
                        "baseHref": "/ngapp/en/"
                    }
                }
            }
            },
```